# Drupal Views - Show "Contribution" + Drupal User fields

Tags: civicontribute, drupal-views

A client requires one of their reports include information from both CiviContribute, but also Drupal user fields (such as login name).

We're trying to build this as a View.

However, when creating the view, and the "Show" dropdown, we select "CiviCRM Contribution", but cannot get access to the "Users" fields.

Anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nevermind, figured it out - had to create a Relationship to CiviCRM Contacts: Drupal ID. Issue resolved.